# delegate Not called in OAuth.io

Tags: ios, iphone

OAuth.io delegate method not called..Any ideas?

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <OAuthiOS/OAuthiOS.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<OAuthIODelegate>
{
    OAuthIOModal *authModel;
}
```

**ViewController.m**

```
 authModel = [[OAuthIOModal alloc] initWithKey:@"Yk7aY94Vskjj3b6yDy3tWkBEEXo" delegate:self];
[authModel showWithProvider:@"facebook"];

//On success, the didReceiveOAuthIOResponde delegate method is called:
- (void)didReceiveOAuthIOResponse:(OAuthIORequest *)request
{
// Here you can use the request object to make requests directly
// or store it for later use (e.g. when a button is pressed)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

May be there is some problem in receiving OAuthResponse:-

// Handle errors in the case of an unsuccessful authentication

```
- (void)didFailWithOAuthIOError:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"Failure");
}
```

Check if this method is calling or not. If this is calling means there is no any issue with delegate method.

Thanks.